# How to access the localhost connection to MySQL database through c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

In my C# code, I have this in my App.config

```
<add name="SampleDB" connectionString="Server=.;Database=Sample;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I opened MySQL Command Client, typed in the password, then created the Sample database by typing `CREATE DATABASE SAMPLE;`
However, I cannot connect to the database. Do I need to specify the instance of SQL after `"Server=.`?
Or do I need to open the connection some other way?

Comment: write the name of the Database Server ,mysql in your case in the Server field value e.g " Server=locahost:8080;..."

Comment: @Aqib I'm running it on 3306. I tried that, still doesn't work.

Comment: you are using a "Trusted_Connecion=True" that works with windows authentication but that is not available on mysql supply userid and password in the connection string like this "UID=USER;PWD=PASS;

Answer (score 0):

Bookmark the [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/).  This site provides all types of connectionstring information for all types of databases and versions of drivers, including MySQL.

```
Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: 3306 is the default for MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Put a piece of code here starting from the declaration of the MySqlConnection object so we can better understand why it is not connecting because the connection string answer above is already correct. If you installed MySQL using default settings, it should be:

```
   <appSettings>
        <add key="MyConnectionSettings" value="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=myDataBase;Uid=root or user;
    Pwd=yourpassword" />


string connectionFromConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyConnectionSettings"];
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionFromConfig)){
con.Open();
   string sql = "SELECT *from yourtable";
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con );
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]+" -- "+rdr[1]);
        }
        rdr.Close();
}
```